# Find Total Days From Date and To Date month wise

Tags: sql-server

I have this type of leave table.

[image]

I want to find total leave days, month and year wise.

what is in where condition.

Comment: Welcome to [so].  We like the table in text format instead of a picture, and also could you show your effort?

Comment: How do you plan to handle the case where a leave spans multiple months?  Have you tried something yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Try This Query, It will also consider Leave taken at year end e.g **2016-12-29 to 2017-01-05**

```
create table #Test(id INT IDENTITY(1,1),from_date datetime,to_date datetime)

insert into #Test values('2016-11-16','2016-11-17')
insert into #Test values('2016-11-22','2016-11-25')
insert into #Test values('2016-09-22','2016-09-25')
insert into #Test values('2016-12-29','2017-01-05')
insert into #Test values('2017-01-08','2017-01-09')

select Sum(Leavestaken) as Leavestaken,LeaveYear,LeaveMonth from(select Sum(DATEDIFF(day,from_date,(case when YEAR(to_date)>YEAR(from_date) then DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, from_date) + 1, 0)) else to_date end))+1) Leavestaken,
YEAR(from_date) as LeaveYear,
MONTH(from_date) as LeaveMonth
from #Test
group by YEAR(from_date),MONTH(from_date)
union all
select Sum(DATEDIFF(day,(case when YEAR(to_date)>YEAR(from_date) then DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, to_date), 0) else from_date end),to_date)+1) Leavestaken,
YEAR(to_date) as LeaveYear,
MONTH(to_date) as LeaveMonth
from #Test
where YEAR(from_date)<>YEAR(to_date)
group by YEAR(to_date),MONTH(to_date)) as tbl
group by LeaveYear,LeaveMonth
order by LeaveYear 

--drop table #Test
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider making each day of leave its own entry. Using ranges will cause issues accounting for days in that range that don't count for holidays or even weekends.

Comment: I agree with you, but you might want to leave this as a comment instead of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(datediff(dd,from_date,to_date)) as  leaves , year(from_date) as [year],month(from_date) as [month] FROM 
(SELECT 1 as Id , 2 as created_by , '2016-11-16' as from_date , '2016-11-17' as to_date
UNION
SELECT 2 as Id , 2 as created_by , '2016-02-10' as from_date , '2016-02-12' as to_date
UNION
SELECT 3 as Id , 2 as created_by , '2016-04-20' as from_date , '2016-04-20' as to_date
UNIOn
SELECT 4 as Id , 2 as created_by , '2016-11-25' as from_date , '2016-11-26' as to_date
UNION
SELECT 5 as Id , 2 as created_by , '2016-11-26' as from_date , '2016-11-28' as to_date
UNION
SELECT 6 as Id , 2 as created_by , '2016-10-10' as from_date , '2016-10-11' as to_date
UNION
SELECT 7 as Id , 2 as created_by , '2016-12-30' as from_date , '2016-12-30' as to_date) a
group by year(from_date),month(from_date),year(to_date),month(to_date)
```

output:

[image]

If needed you can use order by to sort by month and by year.